I cannot build my flutter/unity app: Undefined Symbol CardboardUnity, linker command failed
As I said I cannot build my flutter app with Unity Framework.
These are some logs when build fails:
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _CardboardUnity_setDeviceParametersChanged
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _CardboardUnity_setGraphicsApi
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _CardboardUnity_setScreenParams
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _CardboardUnity_setViewportOrientation
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _CardboardUnity_setWidgetCount
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _CardboardUnity_setWidgetParams
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _UnityPluginLoad
Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
I am not sure where the issue is. I tried to add pod 'GVRSDK' in my Podfile, but it didn't help. I also tried to change ios deploymnet version, disable objc. I removed some dependencies as OneSignal, FirebaseDynamicLinks, but it didn't help.
Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GVRSDK'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
            '$(inherited)',
            'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',
            'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',
            'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',
            'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',
            'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',
            'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',
            'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
      ]
         config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
         config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end

If you need any other information, feel free to ask. Thanks everyone.
